# Speed up (uncachable) MySQL queries

Tags: php, performance, mysqli

I have some PHP session test code - to ensure the logged in user is valid.
I'll just explain some of the functions: `is_logged_in` just checks to see if some session variables are set and `test_duplicate` connects to the database to check if there is a row with a column equaling the value.

```
function check_account(){
  if(is_logged_in()){
    // Destroy session if the user doesn't exist.
    if(test_duplicate("username", $_SESSION["user"])){
      session_destroy();
    }
  }

  if($_SESSION["valid_day"] != date("Ymd")){
    // Destroy session if the key has expired
    session_destroy();
  }
}



function test_duplicate($field, $value){
  $mysqli = database_connect();
  $statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE " . $field . " = ?");
  $statement->bind_param("s", $value);
  $statement->execute();
  $statement->store_result();

  $rows = $statement->num_rows;
  if($rows > 0){
    return FALSE;
  }

  return TRUE;
}

function database_connect(){
  if(!isset($dbconnection)){
    $config = get_configuration();

    // Create connection
    $mysqli = new mysqli($config["hostname"], $config["username"], $config["password"], $config["database"]);

    if($mysqli->connect_error){
      die("<h1>Error 1 :: Critical backend failure</h1>");
    }

    if(!check_tables($mysqli)){
      die("<h1>Error 2 :: Critical backend failure</h1>");
    }

    $dbconnection = $mysqli;

    return $mysqli;
  }else{
    return $dbconnection;
  }
}
```

The problems:

- This `test_duplicate` function takes about 3-4 seconds to complete
- Caching won't work because I need to test that value (it's determining whether the user still exists in the database)

My current solutions (I don't think these are particularly good):

- Only running the code randomly (i.e. a 1/5 chance)
- Not running the code (but then I'm not sure how to implement this alternatively)

Comment: Have your database tables been indexed? Proper indexing makes read operations very fast even on very large (1M+ rows) tables.

Comment: Apart from the previous suggestion: If `test_duplicate()` is causing problems, you should post that function, not the code that is working fine.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes. Moreover, MySQL Workbench executes the query almost instantly (duration: `0.000 sec / 0.000 sec`)

Comment: Oops, yeah forgot that @jeroen Edit: added it

Comment: Have you actually benchmarked this specific isolated function to ensure this is actually what's taking 4 seconds to complete?  You may have other overhead causing your delay - especially if it runs quickly in workbench

Comment: @EatPeanutButter not accurately but replacing the function with `FALSE` brings the speed up to 1 second (and `TRUE` is the same)

Comment: An EXPLAIN query will also reveal whether or not you're using an indexed column. For example - is 'username' indexed?

Comment: Is this a local mysql server? You should check what the bottle-neck is exactly, the connection, the query, etc. And if you are not already, you should open 1 database connection only and share that between your components.

Comment: It is local @jeroen Edit: Good thought, I'll try that

Comment: @JayBlanchard http://imgur.com/VOPFXNX

Comment: @SamMearns Are you storing a crap-ton of data in your session vars?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter Nope. Username (45 chars or less), a date and an integer (less than 10)

Comment: `database_connect()` looks like custom function... What does that do?

Comment: I've modified my `require`'s to `require_once`'s (I forgot to do that) and I made sure there is only one instance of mysqli and that has sped it up to 1.3s. Thanks @jeroen

Comment: @EatPeanutButter added to answer

Comment: One thing, your `database_connect()` function is creating a new connection every time it is called.  the `isset()` test on the first line will always return false because that variable does not exist in your function scope.  Pass a global db connection in, or if you must, use global $dbconnection at the top of the function

Comment: `if($_SESSION["valid_day"] != date("Ymd")){ // Destroy session if the key has expired` - that is not really checking an expiry period as the comment suggests, but effectively simply whether midnight has passed. So you will have arbitrary session lifetimes between almost 24 hours and a couple of seconds ...

Comment: @EatPeanutButter the variable is global

Comment: I think you think it's global. To access a variable on the global scope inside a function, you must either pass it in or use the global keyword inside the function.  You have done neither.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: @EatPeanutButter It's global. I tested it

Comment: @sam Good luck then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest:

1. Add debug code to measure how much time it takes for each line of code in `test_duplicate` function.
2. Caching the connection and share it amongst your components like @jeroen suggests in the comments.
3. Instead of selecting all fields with `select *`, return a single integer value.  Better still instead of hadling it as a row returning query, hadle it as a scalar query that returns a single value.

**Update**

Here's a query that returns 1 if there is a row with a specified value in `username`; or 0 if no matching row exists:

```
select
  ifnull(
    (
      select
        1 as user_exists
      from
        dual
      where
        exists(
          select * from users where username = 'test2'
        )
    ), 0) as result
from dual
```

Comment: So you mean `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: Also, the `database_connect` function is taking longest and it's where I define `$mysqli`